# What does this type of syntax mean in a while loop declaration?

Tags: python

```
while b:
   b -= 2
```

What is the condition in a line written like this? Does it default to while b > 0?

Comment: Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983695/4650297) that might help.

Comment: Assuming `b` is a number, it means `while b!=0:`

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: Why has **no one** mentioned that `b` *must be even and positive*, otherwise the code will run in an infinite loop? If this is satisfied, the code will execute until it reaches `0`, which will satisfy the `while` condition and exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to try it. Try running:

```
b=10

while b:
    print(b)
    b-=2
```

and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it sure does. `b > 0`.

```
b = 10
while b:
    print(b)
    b -= 1
```

A simple `print()` statement should let you know when the loop terminates.

Furthermore, this does not mean that the loop will not run for negative `b < 0`. This means that the loop will terminate then `b = 0`.

```
b = -1
while b:
    print(b)
    b -= 1
```

Goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: Assuming `b` is a number, it means `b!=0`, rather than `b>0`

Comment: You are right. Expanded the answers to account for your reasoning. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This basically checks if b is  `True`, inside the while loop it does `b -= 2`